# Android CTS : CTS does not run default test cases

Tags: android, cts

I am trying to run Android CTS tests from  Windows using command mode for android-cts-5.0_r2-linux_x86-arm

When I run run cts --plan CTS ..its get start but shows start test of 0 packages, containing 0 test cases. & create result file at C:\android-cts\repository\Results

where as CTS is a default plan which has plenty of test cases ..need your help guys..to solve this. why test cases are not running on device

Comment: Have you followed setup steps properly? [CTS](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/setup.html) Are you running on actual device or emulator? Make sure you run `adb install -r android-cts/repository/testcases/CtsDeviceAdmin.apk`

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might still have this problem, check if you are using the correct version of the CTS. `Android 6.0 R18 Compatibility Test Suite (CTS) - x86` is for android devices running on x86, `Android 6.0 R18 Compatibility Test Suite (CTS) - ARM` is for android devices running on ARM.